# Ester vs ether links: Why are archaeal cell membranes more resistant to high temperatures and acidity than bacterial and eukaryotic membranes?

Tags: organic-chemistry, structural-biology

The phospholipids composing the cell membranes of eukaryotes and bacteria contain ester links between the glicerol and the fatty acids. Archaeal membranes, instead, are composed of phospholipids containing ether links between a glicerol and an isoprene chain:

[image: Comparison between the membrane lipids of *Bacteria*, *Eukarya* and *Archaea*]

My microbiology teacher explained that these differences, mainly the ester vs ether links, were determinant to maintain the archeal membranes stable in environments with high temperatures and acidity, but she didn't go into much detail on why. I would like to know the specific chemical reasons why.

(Disclaimer: Considering I'm interested only in the organic chemistry involving this situation, and not in specific archeal phisiology or biology in general, I found it adequate to post this question here in the "Chemistry" cathegory.)

Comment: hmm... Ether should undergo SN2 reaction with an acid to produce alcohol, right? (confuzzled)

Comment: Put simply esters are easily cleaved by nucleophiles, whether enzymes or simpler species, and ethers are not.

Comment: This is an interesting question. It might be because temperature rise favours elimination (separation between the glicerol and fatty acid, which would increase enthropy), and a deprotonated fatty acid is a much better leaving group than an alkoxide (deprotonated alcohol), because the negative charge is less localized. Therefore the high temperatures archaea are subject to, sometimes over 100 C, could release the fatty acids and destroy the membrane. I`m not sure about this, though. Also, a carbonyl group tends to be more reactive, especially as an electrophile.

Comment: @JoaoBrinco I think you can try to put this into an answer. On a side note, would the fact that archaebacteria membranes have connected monolayers also be a factor to heat resistance?